# Second python code bs4 and saving data to a text file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have managed to write my 2nd python code and I am trying to extract data from a table on a webpage i.e. www.ksmnet.org. I need the data of the 2nd column of the table which is today's date and I have managed to extract that fine. However I need the data of the 1st column of the data to be saved as a text file containing the data of the 2nd column. So for example if Fajr is 05:00 then I need a text file to be saved as Fajr.txt and inside this text file I need 05:00.

I understand some of the times are not with the ":" symbol and I need to convert them. So for example the ones with 06.00 need to be 06:00.

Here is my code:

```
# import libraries
import json
import urllib.request
#import soupsieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ksmnet.org/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
path = '/srv/docker/homeassistant/prayer/'


table = soup.find('div', id={'prayer': 'listing sortable'})
package = '' ; version = ''
for i in table.select('tr'):
    data = i.select('td')
    if data:
        package = data[0].text.strip()
        version = ' '.join(data[1].text.strip().split())
        print(version)
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to write in a text file.

```
import urllib.request
#import soupsieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ksmnet.org/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
path = '/srv/docker/homeassistant/prayer/'


table = soup.find('div', id={'prayer': 'listing sortable'})
package = '' ; version = ''
for i in table.select('tr'):
    data = i.select('td')
    if data:
        package = data[0].text.strip()
        file = open(package[:-1] +".txt", "w+")
        version =data[1].text.strip().replace('.',':')
        file.write(version)
        file.close()
```

---

OR you can use python **pandas**.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.ksmnet.org/'
df=pd.read_html(url)[0]
for pkg, version in zip(df['Date'],df['06/01']):
    file = open(pkg[:-1] +".txt", "w+")
    version =version.replace('.',':').strip()
    file.write(version)
    file.close()
```

---

UPDATE checking digits

```
import urllib.request
#import soupsieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.ksmnet.org/'
request = urllib.request.Request(url)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
path = '/srv/docker/homeassistant/prayer/'


table = soup.find('div', id={'prayer': 'listing sortable'})
package = '' ; version = ''
for i in table.select('tr'):
    data = i.select('td')
    if data:
        package = data[0].text.strip()
        file = open(package[:-1] +".txt", "w+")
        version =data[1].text.strip().replace('.',':')

        #Check hours
        checkHours = version.split(':')[0]
        if len(checkHours) < 2:
            version ="0" + str(checkHours) +':' + version.split(':')[-1]
           # print(version)
        #Check minutes
        checkMinute = version.split(':')[-1]
        if len(checkMinute) < 2:
            version = version.split(':')[0] + ":" + "0" + str(checkMinute)
            print(version)

        file.write(version)
        file.close()
```

Comment: thanks alot it works perfect. However is there anyway I could get the time to be saved in double digits? so e.g. if the time on the website shows 6:08 I want it to be 06:08 and similarly if its 10:8 I want it to be 10:08. Is that possible? thanks.

Comment: @Ahmed.B : You have to do string manipulation. `version="10:8"
checklast=version.split(':')[-1]
if len(checklast)<2:
    version=version.split(':')[0] + ":" + "0"+str(checklast)
    print(version)`

Comment: is that specific for every time or would that take care for any time? because as you can see on the website the way the time is given some are in the correct format i.e. HH:MM whilst others are not i.e. H:MM or sometimes I have seen HH:M etc

Comment: Basically My code is checking length of the Minutes if length less than 2 means its 10:8 not 10:08 and if it is already 10:08 it won't go to if block.the same logic you could add every where like hours as well.

Comment: ok so I used your code for minutes however I get a syntax error. Here it is :     `version ="10:8" checklast =version.split(':')[-1]
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Is it possible if you could edit your answer and maybe add it there?

Comment: Hey @KunduK you know in your minutes code, I am sorry I need it to be 10:20 instead if 10:02. Because what I realised is that if the time in the website is 10.2 it means 10:20 and not 10:02. Thats a difference of 18mins. is it possible to change the code for minutes? thanks.

Comment: I am having issues with scraping the times from the website. The answer resolves the issue with print but not the actual problem with scraping the prayer times from the table on the website

Comment: is it possible to scrape the prayer times on the website in the other question that I posted? It seems difficult as with my code I am scrapping the whole site and not just the prayer times from the table.

Comment: @Ahmed.B : I have verified that the prayer times are rendered by java scripts hence `beautiful soup` can't help you in this case.If you only need `names` still you can use `beautiful soup`. However for `prayer times` you need to use browser tool like `selenium` to sort this problem.Let me know if you need any solution for `selenium` for the same.